# Unit Testing Event Sequences on Android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to unit test part of an Android application where a class is expected to call a specific sequence of callbacks.  Is there a good mechanism for handling this in the version of JUnit that ships with Android?

So far here's what I've got in mind:

```
testObj.call(new Listener() {
  boolean a = false, b = false, c = false;

  @Override
  public doA() {
    assertFalse(a);
    a = true;
  }

  @Override
  public doB() {
    assertTrue(a);
    assertFalse(b);
    b = true;
  }

  @Override
  public doC() {
    assertTrue(b);
    assertFalse(c);
    c = true;
  });

assertTrue(c); // I know this won't work, but something like this
```

What I'd like is something like...

```
final PhaseTester phazer = new PhaseTester();
testObj.call(new Listener() {
  @Override
  public doA() {
    phazer.doPhase(1);
  }

  @Override
  public doA() {
    phazer.doPhase(2);
  }

  @Override
  public doA() {
    phazer.doPhase(3);
  }
});

assertTrue(phazer.maxPhase(), 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a standard JVM a mocking framework such as Mockito will give you this type of testing. I've never done any Andriod development and realise that traditionally mocking frameworks don't work with the Dalvik JVM. However, I found this post regarding [Roboelectric](http://sdudzin.blogspot.com/2011/01/easy-unit-testing-for-android.html) that will allow you to Unit test your code outside of the Android emulator.

You can then code something like this...

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

@Test
public void testSomething() {

    // create a mock object
    PhaseTester phaser = mock(PhaseTester.class);

    // perform test
    TestObj testObj = new TestObj();
    testObj.call(phaser);

    // verfiy the mock object was called
    verify(phaser).doA();
    verify(phaser).doB();
    verify(phaser).doC();

}
```

Comment: Yep robolectric and mockito, exactly what we use. Only issue is statics :@

Comment: Then you can use [PowerMock with Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) to handle the statics

Comment: you can't with Robolectric. Due to the testrunner being used and some complex behind the scenes sh*t :-)